# Wrong encoding when reading csv file with pyspark

Tags: csv, pyspark, encoding

For my course in university, I run pyspark-notebook docker image

```
docker pull jupyter/pyspark-notebook
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 -v /path/to/my/working/directory:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/pyspark-notebook
```

And then run next python code

```
import pyspark 
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark

listings_df = spark.read.csv("listings.csv", header=True, mode='DROPMALFORMED') 
# adding encoding="utf8" to the line above doesn't help also
listings_df.printSchema()
```

The problem appears during reading a file. It seems that spark reads my file incorrectly (possibly because of encodings problem?) and after reading listings_df has 16494 lines, while the correct number of lines is 16478 (checked with `pandas.read_csv()`). You can see that something definitely is broken also by running

```
listings_df.groupBy("room_type").count().show()
```

which gives next output

```
+---------------+-----+
|      room_type|count|
+---------------+-----+
|            169|    1|
|        4.88612|    1|
|        4.90075|    1|
|    Shared room|   44|
|             35|    1|
|            187|    1|
|           null|   16|
|             70|    1|
|             27|    1|
|             75|    1|
|     Hotel room|  109|
|            198|    1|
|             60|    1|
|            280|    1|
|Entire home/apt|12818|
|            220|    1|
|            190|    1|
|            156|    1|
|            450|    1|
|        4.88865|    1|
+---------------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

while real `room_type` values are only ['Private room', 'Entire home/apt', 'Hotel room', 'Shared room'].

Spark info which might be useful:

```
SparkSession - in-memory

SparkContext

Spark UI

Version
v3.1.2
Master
local[*]
AppName
pyspark-shell
```

And encoding of the file

```
!file listings.csv
listings.csv: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

`listings.csv` is an Airbnb statistics csv file downloaded from [here](http://data.insideairbnb.com/the-netherlands/north-holland/amsterdam/2021-08-06/visualisations/listings.csv)

All run & drive code I've also uploaded to [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14xqGVPDucFZHJPGUnaEdbto-K6jHd7Pp?usp=sharing)

Comment: _It seems that spark reads my file incorrectly…_ Disagree. The file itself is malformed at IDs `[6113864, 10725464, 11233751, 13678506, 15713489, 18623118, 19013423, 27394704, 28892595, 29705321, 29750219, 30758748, 33980766, 34070600, 41442089, 47488890]`. (There are some unwanted line breaks). Maybe your IDs could differ as the file source appears unsafe…

Comment: BTW, those _unwanted line breaks_ are probably  _https://home.unicode.org/U+2029 is used to represents a line break within a paragraph, aka "shift-Enter" or "soft" line break._ And file encoding is definitely **UTF-8**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things that I've found:

1. Some lines have quotes to escape (`escape='"'`)
2. Also [@JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) has mentioned about unwanted line breaks (`multiLine=True`)

That's how you must read it:

```py
input_df = spark.read.csv(path, header=True, multiLine=True, escape='"')

output_df = input_df.groupBy("room_type").count()
output_df.show()
+---------------+-----+
|      room_type|count|
+---------------+-----+
|    Shared room|   44|
|     Hotel room|  110|
|Entire home/apt|12829|
|   Private room| 3495|
+---------------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think encoding the file from here should solve the problem. So you add `encoding="utf8"` to your tuple of the variable `listings_df`.

As shown below:

```py
listings_df = spark.read.csv("listings.csv", encoding="utf8", header=True, mode='DROPMALFORMED')
```

Comment: Tried but this didn't help. I've updated the question with this info